# play precompile command generating only one class file in precompiled folder and not generating class files for controllers,models etc

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x

I have a play framework application built using play 1.2.4, for which when I am running play precompile command from `C:\workspace\depotit\javadev\source\webapps\apiui` (this is where all folders like app, conf, eclipse etc folders are).

The command is generating the precompiled folder with java folder only and that folder contains only `DocViewerPlugin.class` but not other classes of the project, also it's not generating templates folder which contains html files.

Comment: Do you have any error in your log file ?

Answer (score 1):

Some generic trick to find what files have been added or modified is to version the folder, do the modifications and then check the differences. For example in play framework check what modifications do the precompile command does to one of the zen-contacts sample project in the play distribution this are the commands using git version control:

Move to the project folder.
    cd /home/hans/Descargas/play-1.2.5.3/samples-and-tests/zencontact/

Remove any previous temporary folder.
    play clean

These three commands create a repository and version the current state of files and folders.
    git init
    git add .
    git commit -m"Initial release"

Do our command
    play precompile

This last command will show what modifications to the file system the command did.
    git status

Finally remove the version control from your project or keep it. You should use some kind o version control.
    rm -rf .git